# I get error when create distributed table on citus (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, citus

I created a table on Citus:
`CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable`

Then I created function that gets data from table myschema.mytable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myschema.myfunction(id INT)
RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE approved_count INT;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(id) INTO approved_count 
FROM myschema.mytable
WHERE id = $1 AND is_deleted = FALSE AND is_flagged = TRUE;
RETURN approved_count;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Then I added the constraint on table myschema.mytable:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint CHECK ((myschema.myfunction()=(0)));
```

All queries above were executed successfully.

Finally, I created a distributed table:

```
SELECT create_distributed_table('myschema.mytable', 'tenant_id');
```

And I got the error:

```
ERROR:  function myschema.myfunction() does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
CONTEXT:  while executing command on 10.0.0.***:****
SQL state: 42883
```

I tried to run queries in the other order. I created a table, distributed table, and function successfully. But I couldn't add constraint and got the same error.

As I understand my Worker does not see my function. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Where is the body of the function? `CREATE FUNCTION myschema.myfunction()`.

Comment: Updated. I think that the body does not matter because it does not work with other functions too.

Comment: Maybe you are correct but the `function myschema.myfunction() does not exist` confuses me. Did you commit each transaction separately?

Comment: Yes, I executed each query separately, step by step. This function exists in my schema. But for the distributed table, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citus currently does not propagate `CREATE FUNCTION` queries to worker nodes. You need to manually create the function in the workers yourself.

You can also use the following query to manually create your function in your worker nodes:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM run_command_on_workers($cmd$
  CREATE FUNCTION myschema.myfunction(id INT) RETURNS INT AS
  $$ DECLARE approved_count INT;
    BEGIN 
    SELECT 
      COUNT(id)
    INTO
      approved_count 
    FROM 
      myschema.mytable 
    WHERE 
      id = $1 
      AND is_deleted = FALSE 
      AND is_flagged = TRUE;
    RETURN approved_count;
    END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
$cmd$);
```

You may need to create `myschema` on the worker nodes as well (depending on your Citus version). You can also do this using `run_command_on_workers()` udf with a `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS` command.

You can check out the documentation for `run_command_on_workers()` [here](http://docs.citusdata.com/en/v8.3/develop/reference_propagation.html?highlight=run_command_on_workers#running-on-all-workers).

FYI: I am currently working on a feature to distribute functions in worker nodes. We plan to ship it in the next Citus major release

Edit: `create_distributed_function` UDF is there in Citus >= `v9.0` You can see the docs at https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v9.0/develop/api_udf.html#create-distributed-function and some more in https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v9.0/faq/faq.html#how-do-i-create-database-roles-functions-extensions-etc-in-a-citus-cluster